# JQuery changes not reflected in postback

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have two asp:BulletedLists, one is populated on Page_Load and the other is empty. The user can drag and drop < li >'s between them, the meat of that drag-n-drop is

```
    function Move(element, source, target) {
        var newLI = document.createElement("li");
        var sourceBL = document.getElementById(source);
        var targetBL = document.getElementById(target);

        newLI.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
        sourceBL.removeChild(element);
        targetBL.appendChild(newLI);
    }
```

I create a new element so that it aligns itself within the asp:BulletedList rather than placing itself where the mouse is released.

The problem is I need to know what is where on postback, the second asp:BulletedList is always empty and the first asp:BulletedList populates itself with the original values even though I do not clear or repopulate them.

```
    foreach (ListItem li in blSelectedDocuments.Items) // .Items is empty
    {

    }
```

Comment: do you have `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` in your `Page_Load` function?

Comment: I believe that on every PostBack, all the unregistered controls got lost. The ones you're adding via JS.

Comment: Yes, definitely not resetting the two lists in my code

Comment: MelanciaUK, is there a way around that? I'm a WinForms man at heart.

Comment: Changes you make in javascript are not reflected on postback. You'll have to serialize the changes and put it in a hidden field or post it via ajax.

Comment: @JasonP just answered the question for you.

Comment: @JasonP any code you can put into my example is appreciated.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gHSPU/. My example is very crude, but it should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horrifically, none of that worked. I'm on SharePoint and the Session wasn't enabled (or whatever) because of some deep dark corner of SharePoint that the asp.config file is located in. Neither did ViewState work in the similar manner. Maybe the AJAX half of that would have worked, but I never got that far.

The solution I got to work was to create a hidden input field, write the order of the asp:BulletedList to that hidden field to go with the postback via the Submit button. Thanks JasonP for serialisation fiddle.

NOTE: I tried some other suggestions I found on the web, using a Label/TextBox with ViewState and/or Readonly properties set did not work for me. Label worked to change text within the page but did not persist on postback.

Answer (score 0):

In the past with working with jQuery plugins on ASP.NET WebForms pages, I have used AJAX to send the updated data back to an ASP.NET AJAX Page Method and then stored the changes into `Session` cache. Then upon postback, the `Page_Load` would look into the `Session` to see what order the values in the list were (I had a drag and drop list for the order of display of a report).

Mock code example:

JavaScript:

```
function Move(element, source, target) {
    var newLI = document.createElement("li");
    var sourceBL = document.getElementById(source);
    var targetBL = document.getElementById(target);

    newLI.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
    sourceBL.removeChild(element);
    targetBL.appendChild(newLI);

    // TODO: Serialize source and target lists to JSON to pass to the server
    var serializedData = {};

    // Use jQuery.ajax() to call ASP.NET AJAX Page Method
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PageName.aspx/UpdateListsInSessionCache",
        data: serializedData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            // Do something here when the AJAX calls completes
        }
    });
}
```

ASP.NET Code-behind (C#)

```
using System.Web.Services;

[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateListsInSessionCache(List<ListItem> source, List<ListItem> target)
{
    Session["SourceList"] = source;
    Session["TargetList"] = target;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create new lists so we have something empty and not null to work with
    var source = new List<ListItem>();
    var target = new List<ListItem>();

    // Always check for values in Session cache and update if there are values
    if (Session["SourceList"] != null)
    {
        source = Session["SourceList"] as List<ListItem>;
    }

    if (Session["TargetList"] != null)
    {
        target = Session["TargetList"] as List<ListItem>;
    }

    // Do something with source and target lists
}
```

Comment: @ColinSteel - see updated answer, it is off the top of my head so please forgive me if it is not 100% complete or accurate.